# Google Docs with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-docs-api

Now, newbie question here.

1 - I would like to know if there's a way to view a google drive (google doc) document in a browser using php/codeigniter?

2 - Can I edit it directly from that view?

3 - I found others using Zend GData, but is it only limited to spreadsheets?

Can I possibly use codeigniter for this?

Comment: If you can do it with php, you can most likely do it with CodeIgniter. Are you wishing for a library, or what's your goal?

Comment: Yup. A php or codeigniter library would fit into purpose.
I would like to have a web page that could let users access a shared file without logging in into their google doc and make collaborative reviews and comments or even involve live editing on the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has an [API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/) for Docs. I haven't used it, but according to it's table of contents you can do a bunch with it. Like Robin said, it you can do it with PHP you can with CI.
Perhaps you could be more clear on what you want to accomplish. It's not entirely clear right now.